# How to (COUNT) get total rows belong to post using inner join php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using inner join to list posts and their categories and comments,
Like this:

```
    if($stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN categories ON posts.cat_id = categories.cat_id
    INNER JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comment_id 
    WHERE user_id = :sid")){
    $stmt->execute(array('sid'=>$sid));
```

Then doing while loop to list them

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

And usaqe is :

```
$row['category'];
```

I want to get total rows of the comments belong to post and show them like :
Total comments on post : `$row['total_coments'];`

İs it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this , assuming the comment_id is unique,

```
if($stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT posts.*,(select count(comment_id) from 
comments) 
as total_coments
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN categories ON posts.cat_id = categories.cat_id
INNER JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comment_id 
WHERE user_id = :sid")){
$stmt->execute(array('sid'=>$sid));
```

Comment: When I use it like so : `SELECT posts.*,(select count(comment_id) from comments) 
as total_coments` then it ignores categories, Having error **Undefined index: cat_name**

Comment: Having same error, I tried this way ` posts.*, categories.*,  comments.*,`  it works now, Thanks alot budd.